# If $u - v = \frac{\cos x + \sin x - e^{-y}} {2 \cos x - \cosh y} $ and $f( \pi /2) = 0$ determine the function $f(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> If $u - v = \dfrac{\cos x + \sin x - e^{-y}} {2 \cos x - \cosh y} $ and $f\left( \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) = 0$, determine the analytic function $f(z) = u + iv$.

I don't know how to solve this. I don't know where to start?

Comment: Is there any typo?  $$\cot \frac{z}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{\cosh y-\cos x}+\frac{i\sinh x}{\cos x-\cosh y}$$

Comment: If $f(z)=u+iv$ is analytic, then $\Delta u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0, \Delta v=v_{xx}+v_{yy}=0$ and hence $\Delta(u-v)=0$. However  your $u-v$ does not satisfies $\Delta(u-v)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note if $f(z)=u+iv$ is analytic, then $u,v$ satisfy
$$ u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x. $$
Let $u-v=g(x,y)$. Note
$$ f'(z)=u_x+iv_x\tag{1} $$
or
$$ f'(z)=v_y-iu_y. \tag{2}$$
Then by (1)
$$ f'(z)=(u-v)_x+(1+i)v_x=g_x+(1+i)v_x  \tag{3}$$
and by (2)
$$ f'(z)=(1-i)v_y-i(u-v)_y=(1-i)v_y-ig_y.  \tag{4}$$
Adding (3) to (4) gives
$$ 2f'(z)=(g_x-ig_y)+(1-i)(v_y+iv_x).$$
Thus we have
$$ 2f'(z)=(g_x-ig_y)+(1-i)f'(z)$$
from which we have
$$ f'(z)=\frac{1-i}{2}(g_x-ig_y). $$
I will come back.

Comment: The main problem is integration, Just  _The detail is omitted_.